# Cant find element in xpath (Instagram, selenium, python)

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Ok ive been trying to make a instagram bot that sends back the src link for a post but im having trouble, i keep getting the error "*selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img*" when im trying to get the xpath for the element with the src in it. can anyone help?
Link: https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/ .

```
    def dm_check(self, driver):
        print("dm_check starts here")

        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/div').click()
        except:
            self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/')
            print("Refreshing...")
            time.sleep(10)
            self.dm_check(self.driver)


        print("dm_check stops here")

        self.download(self.driver)
    
    def download(self, driver):
        print("download starts here")

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/img').click()
        post = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img').get_attribute("src")
        print(str(post))

        print("download ends here")

        self.dmessage(self.driver)
```

Comment: Ok two things use a webdriver wait  and check if it's under an iframe.

Comment: If those two issues aren't the problem it's your xpath that's the problem so just inspect the element and copy it's xpath from the developer tools.

Comment: sorry im new to selenium so how do i check that its a iframe and thats how i got the xpath, i went into inspect and copied it @arundeepchohan

Comment: Go to the developers tools search for iframe and see if it's the parent div to that tag.

Comment: If your tag works it also should pop up in the developer tools as well.

Comment: thank you, ive got it working now

Comment: np have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

This exception appears in some basic cases.

- This item is not on the page. The page did not load or the page is invalid.
- The path to the element is incorrect.
- And, if the first two points match, then you really need to see if there is a frame.

To do this, you need to try switching to a frame using the following code.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='Dialogue Window']")
```

Where you can replace "//iframe[@name='Dialogue Window']" with your identifier.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Just insert before searching for an element.
The element will be found if it really was in the frame.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Just in case, here's the code to exit the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Yep ! I think you re not in the right frame... Maybe there is a popup or something like that. If it's the case you have to close it. To switch to the active element :

```
driver.switch_to_active_element()
```

Then you can find the "close" button or something. After closing it you ll be able to continue your webscraping on the page and locate the element you need ;)